# Search in File with Hashmap

Tags: c, algorithm, hash

I am working with a C project. I have a file containing item details which can be 5000 - 10000 or more in number. My target is to retrieve an item detail with an item reference.

What I currently do is create hash values for the item reference of each item details and store in a file.

The location of hash value will be the location of the item detail.

Whenever I get an item reference, I create hash value and search for matching one in my new file of hash values and get the location. With this location I get the actual item detail.

This is a slow process. Can anyone suggest more fast method?

Comment: This isn't very clear; are you essentially asking how a [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) works?

Comment: It shouldn't be slow. This is a standard algorithm. However if you post your code people can help, otherwise no one can help.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: In my case the Hash value doesn't says the location of the data. The location of my Hash value in the file gives me the location of data in another file. But if in anyway if my Hash value points to data location, I could sort the hash values and store, so that search becomes easier. Is there any chance like that?

Comment: You need the hashtable to find the _location_ in the file. You need to read the file to get the actual _item_.

Comment: Well, if you have only 10000 items or even 100000 then store your index in the memory. You will save one file access.

Comment: @wildplasser: My hashtable is a normal file. Do I have to do a sequential search to get my hash value??

Comment: @Marian: The count increase on go.. And I am creating this index file in desktop and loading it to a device.. So i need it in a file

Comment: No, of course not. Calculating the hashvalue should get you to the correct location of the entry in the file (or to the chain that contains that entry)

Comment: You shall use records of the same size in the file and to seek to the position returned by hash function. Also if you know all hashed values on a desktop and then transfer them to a device where they are not changed anymore, you may consider to compute a perfect hash function.

Comment: @Marian: does the hash value itself says location of data or the location of hash value says the location of data. Because I am getting  hash values like 3076803778, which can't be any location.. right?

Comment: Which part is slow?  If finding the hash value in your index file and the values are comparable, then you might organize the file with something like a [B-Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree); alternatively, you might store your indexes in an actual hash table.  If it's searching the large file, are you using `fseek()`?

Comment: @JohnC:
`iBarcodeHash = getHashValue (cBarcode); 
for (iCount =1; fgets (cLineData, HASH_MAX_LENGTH,fpIndex);++iCount)
{
 iFileReadHash = atoll (cLineData);
 if (iBarcodeHash == iFileReadHash)
  {
   getRecordFileData(iCount, fpData, cRecordBarcode);
   if (0 == strcmp (cBarcode, cRecordBarcode) )
   {
    return HASH_OPERATIONOK;
   }`
this is how I check for hash code,

Comment: @JohnC:
and below is how i get data:
`void getRecordFileData(int iRecordPosition,FILE *fpData,char *cRecordBarcode)
{
 TIM_DAT tim_dat_begin,tim_dat_end;
 int iLineNumber = 0,
  iBarcodeLength = 0,
  iRecordDataLength = 0;
  char cLineData[RECORD_LENGTH+1];
  char cString[RECORD_LENGTH+1];
  for (iLineNumber = 1; (fgets(cLineData,RECORD_LENGTH+1,fpData))
  &&(iRecordPosition>iLineNumber);++iLineNumber);
  strcpy (cString, cLineData);
  strcpy (cRecordBarcode, strtok(cString, ","));
  iBarcodeLength = strlen(cRecordBarcode);

Comment: iRecordDataLength = ((strlen (cLineData)) - (iBarcodeLength + 1)); // \n char size is reduced.
  strncpy (cRecordData, (cLineData + iBarcodeLength), iRecordDataLength);
 return;
}`

Comment: @Abin, you should probably get that up in the question where people will see it and where the formatting is better.  But that doesn't really answer the question:  Which part of that code runs slower than you would expect?

Comment: @JohnC: The case is I have saved hash values and data in two files. And each time I get a key I generate the hash and search the file. With that I get the data location. This search for key is time consuming... I hope I could resolve this by loading the hash values initially into an array. I'm trying to implement this now..

Comment: @Abin, OK, if searching your index file is the problem, then you'll want to index your index.  If you can sort your hash values (which will take time), then you can build something like a B-Tree in memory to tell you where in the index to find the hash value.  You'll also get a performance boost by pulling the entire index into memory, but depending on the number of records, that might exhaust memory for actual work.